# Drawing rectangle on python Tkinter canvas that covers the entire canvas does not show border on top and left

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a rectangle inside a Tkinter (Python 2.7) canvas that is the same dimension as the canvas. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=100, height=100, backround="yellow")
self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100)
```

This draws a rectangle but I can't see the left and top border of the rectangle. If I start the rectangle from let's say 5,5 instead of 0,0 I can see the border of the rectangle. Any ideas as to why this happens, and how I can get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the canvas border is included in the drawable region. Try setting the `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` attributes to zero on the canvas.

You'll also want to adjust the coordinates of your rectangle to end at 99, since counting starts at zero (if the width is 100, the coordinates go from 0 to 99).

Comment: That is correct. To add to your answer, the border of the Canvas is usually by default set to 1 pixels, so by setting the upper left corner  to `(0,0)`, the border of the rectangle become the same as that one of the Canvas which can't be drawn  because they sit inside the canvas coordinate system (you can't draw in the space it occupies). So if the OP wants to keep things to default, he can move the upper left corner to  the co-ordinate system by the size of the border, meaning that he has to type `(1,1)` instead of `(0,0)` and the instruction `w.create_rectangle(1, 1, 100, 100)` is valid.

Comment: Setting both `borderwidth` and `highlightthickness` to 0 worked for me. However, as you already mentioned this caused the right and bottom outlines to be rendered outside the canvas since my coordinates were off by 1 (i.e they should have been (99,99) not (100,100)